autoinstall cloud-init on several clients serving from one server with individual configrations
Is there a possibility to server mutliple configuration files (in particular user-data) from a webserver (as described in Autoinstall quick start and cloudinit.readthedocs and Cloud config examples) and have several clients booting at the same time fetching their individual configuration (maybe by MAC address or by a parameter set in the boot command line)?

This question is similar to: Fetch autoinstall based on MAC. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
